# rust convert binary int to string or array of numbers

Tags: arrays, string, rust, binary, integer

i have an integer like this:

```
let x: u8 = 0b101;
```

and i need to convert it to string like this:

```
let s = "101";
```

or array:

```
let a = [1, 0, 1];
```

but rust by default converting already converted binary int to decimal to string
so i receiving:

```
let x = 0b101;
println!("{:?}", x.to_string()); // 5
```

how to convert binary number to string or array without this?

i tried x.to_ne_bytes() and to_be_bytes() but it`s also returning alredy converted do dec number

Answer (score 0):

Simply use binary format:

```rust
let x = 0b101;
let s = format!("{:b}", x);
```